# Ticket Prize Probability

Tags: probability

In a lottery $40$ tickets are sold and there are $3$ prizes. What is the probability that a girl buying $5$ tickets wins at least $1$ prize? 
Answer is $667/1976$, how do you get there?
I tried finding the probability of getting exactly $1$, $2$ and $3$ prizes but I still don't know how to do it. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: It is easiest to first find the probability of no prizes. There are $\binom{40}{5}$ ways to choose $5$ tickets, There are $\binom{37}{5}$ ways to buy $5$ loser tickets, so the probability of no prize is $\binom{37}{5}/\binom{40}{5}$. But maybe better is to work directly with probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

First we do it the way you proposed. For this problem, it is a little inefficient, but the idea will be needed at other times.

There are $\binom{40}{5}$ ways to choose $5$ tickets from $40$.

We find the number of $5$-ticket hands that win exactly $1$ prize. There are $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to choose the "good" ticket, and for each of these ways there are $\binom{37}{4}$ ways to choose the "bad" tickets, for a total of $\binom{3}{1}\binom{37}{4}$ one prize hands.

Thus the probability of winning exactly one prize is $\dfrac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{37}{4}}{\binom{40}{5}}$.

Similarly, the number of two prize hands is $\binom{3}{2}\binom{37}{3}$.

Thus the probability of winning exactly two prizes is $\dfrac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{37}{3}}{\binom{40}{5}}$.

Finally,  the probability of winning exactly three  prizes is $\dfrac{\binom{3}{3}\binom{37}{2}}{\binom{40}{5}}$.

Add up.

**Another way:** We find the probability $p$ of winning **no prize**. Then the probability of winning at least one is $1-p$.

There are $\binom{37}{5}$ hands in which all the tickets are bad. It follows that
$$p=\dfrac{\binom{37}{5}}{\binom{40}{5}}.$$

**Still another way:** Again, we first find the probability of no prize. Suppose she checks her tickets one by one to see whether she has won something.

The probability the first ticket is bad is $\frac{37}{40}$. Given that the first ticket was bad, the probability the second ticket is bad is $\frac{36}{39}$, for there are only $36$ bads left. So the probability the first two tickets are bad is $\frac{37}{40}\cdot \frac{36}{39}$.  Given the first two were bad, the probability the third is bad is $\frac{35}{38}$. And so on. Thus
$$p=\frac{37}{40}\cdot \frac{36}{39}\cdot \frac{35}{38}\cdot \frac{34}{37}\cdot \frac{33}{36}.$$
To evaluate, it can be useful to do some cancellation.

Comment: Does (32) mean 3^2?

Comment: $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways to choose $k$ objects from $n$ objects. This is the standard mathematical notation, but in school maybe you call it $C(n,k)$ or $C^n_k$, or something similar. It is $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. In particular, $\binom{3}{2}$ is $\frac{3!}{2!1!}$, or more simply $3$.  In all but the last way, you will have to do more complicated evaluations. For example $\binom{40}{5}=\frac{40!}{5!35!}$. Some calculators will evaluate $\binom{n}{k}$ for you. The key probably says $C^n_k$. Many programs, such as Wolfram Alpha, will also do it.